# "How to make a turing machine of {w ∈ {a,b}∗ | 2na(w) = 3nb(w)}. My question is in how to apply the condition"

Tags: automata, turing-machines

This is an assignment I have for a module. I understand turing machines, the problem for me is how do I make sure the ratio is maintained. I can see how one would check this if we can check for every 5 digits without being intermixed (e.g. {aababaabab}) but for the words like: {aaaaaabbbb}. Very lost.

Any tips/help?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this means that the ration n/m = 3/2 where n is the number of occurrences of a and m is the number of occurrences of b.

To solve the general case, lots of solutions are possible; here is one that might be easy to understand.

1. scanning left to right, find 3 occurrences of a. Skip over A, B and b. Change the three a you find to A and go back to the beginning of the tape. If you hit the end of the tape without crossing over any a or b, halt-accept. If you hit the end of the tape having seen some a and b but not at least three a, halt-reject. Otherwise, continue to step 2.
2. scanning left to right, find 2 occurrences of b. Skip over A, B and a. Change the two b you find to B and go back to the beginning of the tape. If you hit the end without seeing at least two b, halt-reject. Repeat starting from step 1 until you halt-accept or halt-reject.

Examples:

```
aababaabab    aaaaaabbbb     aaaaabbbb
AAbAbaabab    AAAaaabbbb     AAAaabbbb
AABABaabab    AAAaaaBBbb     AAAaaBBbb
AABABAAbAb    AAAAAABBbb     halt_reject
AABABAABAB    AAAAAABBBB
halt_accept   halt_accept
```